# How to run certutil commands saved in a txt file on Azure windows VM using Azure DevOps and copy the output from the VM to ADO or local machine

Tags: azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I want to create a custom certificate request on Azure Windows VM by using certutil like
*certreq -new "request command file.txt" "csroutput.txt"*.
How can push the execution of file "request command file.txt" on Azure Windows VM from Azure DevOps and also copy the Output that is Certificate Signing Request(CSR output) generated on that machine.

"request command file.txt" file contains some commands to perform the required operation. this file needs to be executed in Command prompt on the VM. How to do this from ADO?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `PowerShell on Target Machines` task in your ADO pipeline to execute your script on the Azure VM. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops).

You can also check out [SSH Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops), which enables you to connect to a remote machine using SSH and run commands or a script.

To copy the output to ADO. You can use [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to publish the output to ADO server. And then you can use [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to download the output to the ADO agent machine.

If you want to copy to a local machine. You can use [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) or [remote copy task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotecopysaeid&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) to copy the output to your local machine after the output is downloaded to the agent machine by `Download Build Artifacts task`

You can also build a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on you local machine, And run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent. Then you can use `Download Build Artifacts task` to download the output to your local machine directly without using the remote copy tasks.

Comment: Thank you Levi. Using the "PowerShell on Target Machines", how can I push the code stored in Notepad file to Azure VM and execute and run it inside a command prompt in VM?

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni You can use  Windows Machine File Copy task or remote copy task  mentioned above to copy the file to Azure VM. Or you can build a self-hosted agent on the Azure VM